# Do you use the phrase "that which" for the apposition?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The insect propagates best near "disturbed land," that which is being cultivated by humans.

I saw this type of sentence. Do you use this kind of syntax. Would it be possible that it is colloquial?

Some explain that "that" following "disturbed land," is the apposition and also the antecedent of the "which". I often see "that which" phrases but these did not have this apposition like structure.

Comment: I couldn't make sense of your example sentence. As for "that which", this is related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66453/that-which-used-together.

Comment: Thank you, Damkerng. The usages you showed are understandable for me. I think the example I show takes the same usage, but the syntax is different from the sentence in the link.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's possible to use *that which* in appositives, but I don't know about whether it's colloquial or not. I think *wh-word* versions or ordinary relative clauses may be more common.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of syntax is certainly used, and I don't have the impression it is colloquial.

What is confusing about your example sentence, is that you punctuated it as is *disturbed land* is direct speech, but in reality, you're quotes are what is sometimes called *scare quotes*. In that case I would *not* put the comma inside the quotes:

> The insect propagates best near "disturbed land", that which is being cultivated by humans.

Alternatively, do *not* use scare quotes at all. *Disturbed land* has a special meaning in this context, which is indicated by the quotes, but you can convey the same thing with *italics*:

> The insect propagates best near *disturbed land*, that which is being cultivated by humans.

That said, let's look at the *that which* construction.

I would agree that *that [land] which is cultivated by humans* is the apposition of *disturbed land*. They describe the same concept, the land where the insect propagates best.

*That* is indeed the antecedent of *which*, but it might be easier to realize that *land* has been elided (as I indicated earlier):

> That **land**, which is cultivated by humans.

In this case, *that land* is the antecedent of *which*.

To illustrate the apposition, we can inverse the two parts:

> That **land**, which is cultivated by humans, is called *disturbed land*.

And even in the complete sentence:

> The insect propagates best near that land which is being cultivated by humans, "disturbed land".

In this version, we could omit *that* without changing the meaning of the sentence much.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is fine.  It's rather the opposite of colloquial—most people don't talk like this in everyday speech.

We can analyze it as ellipsis, if we like:

> The insect propagates best near "disturbed land," that **land** [ *which* ___ is being cultivated by humans. ]

Here, the relative clause *which is being cultivated* modifies *that <strike>land</strike>*.  The phrase *that <strike>land</strike>* plays the subject role in the relative clause.

Taken as a whole, *that <strike>land</strike> which is being cultivated by humans* is a (non-restrictive) appositive phrase which **defines** the term in quotes, "disturbed land".